# Iam trying to send message from command prompt to slack channel using jenkins but iam getting error

Tags: windows, jenkins

if I try,
(case-1)

```
cd /path/
npm install slack-cli -g

slackcli -h "channelname" -t "token" -u "from_name" -m "message"
```

(in one Execute Windows batch command)

the third line is not executing,the message is not going

if I try,
(case-2)

```
cd /path/
npm install slack-cli -g
```

(in one Execute Windows batch command)

```
slackcli -h "channelname" -t "token" -u "from_name" -m "message"
```

(in another Execute Windows batch command)

I am getting error:

```
'slackcli' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 0):

[As seen here](https://superuser.com/a/915677/141), the installation syntax should rather be:

```
npm install -g slack-cli
```

There was installation issue before ([candrholdings/slack-cli issues 12](https://github.com/candrholdings/slack-cli/issues/12)) but that should work now ([PR 27](https://github.com/candrholdings/slack-cli/pull/27)).

Comment: in case 1, third line is not executing(the message is not going),
in case 2,iam getting error :
`'slackcli' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file` If i change `npm install slack-cli -g` to `npm install -g slack-cli` also,
in case 1, third line is not executing(the message is not going),
in case 2,iam getting error :`'slackcli' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file`

Comment: @sunny Can you do a search on your drive to look for 'slackcli' (you might find a slackcli.exe): in which folder do you find it?

Comment: i did not find slackcli.exe,but i found slackcli and slackcli.cmd in npm folder

Comment: Great. Is that npm folder in your %PATH%?